# RecyclerView: why is wrong Item removed from SQLlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that uses a `SQLite` `database` to store user input that is collected and then shown on a `CardView`.  I am trying to add a **`removeItem`** method to delete a `CardView` from the `RecyclerView` list.  The **`removeItem`** method is triggered by an `onItemLongClick` from the Adapter that is working fine.  It launches a `DialogFragment` that asks the user to confirm the deletion.  The dialog launches properly and the `SQLite` delete method works to remove a row from the database but it is removing the wrong row.  So the wrong `CardView` is removed.  What am I missing here?

> ContactListAdapter file:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ContactHolder>{

private List<Contact> contactList;
private Context context;

private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
}


      public Contact getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
      }  

    @Override
    public ContactHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent, false);

    final ContactHolder contactHolder = new ContactHolder(view);


    // Attach a LongClick listener to the items's (row) view.
    contactHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            int adapterPos = contactHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // get the item position.
            if (adapterPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                    recyclerItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(adapterPos, contactHolder.itemView);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return contactHolder;
}
```

> SQLite file:

```
public void delete(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = ContactField.COLUMN_ID + " LIKE ?";        
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(id) };
    db.delete(ContactField.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
}
```

> from DialogFragment file:

```
    // When the user clicks "OK" on the dialog, delete the CardView's data 
    // from the database and then re-set the RecyclerViewAdapter.
    Button btnOK = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Run the MainActivity removeItem method to:
            // 1) delete the onLongClicked item from the database,
            // 2) load the remaining database data into a new ArrayList,
            // 3) clear the Adapter and then
            // 4) set the Adapter and LayoutManager.
            **((MainActivity)getActivity()).removeItem(position);**

            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

> from MainActivity file:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
    ActActivity.start(this, contactListAdapter.getItem(position));
}

@Override
public void onItemLongClick(int position, View view) {        
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    DeleteCardViewFragment delCardViewDialog = new DeleteCardViewFragment();
    delCardViewDialog.show(fm,"delcardview dialog");
}

// The DeleteCardViewFragment runs this method when the user confirms via a
// dialog that they want to delete an item from the RecyclerView list.
public void removeItem(int position) {
    **sqLiteDB.delete(contactListAdapter.getItem(position).getId());**
    contactListAdapter.clear();
    loadData();
    lvContact.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    lvContact.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);
}
```

Comment: What does getId() return? Are you sure its value is the same as row's ID in a database?

Comment: Yes, getId() returns _id which is set up in the model class.

Comment: You should walk through the whole process with a debugger and see which value is passed between all the methods. For example, it will be interesting to know where is the position in DialogFragment taken from.

Comment: Agree.  I'm new to Android and have zero experience with debugger but breaking up to test should help solve.

Comment: OK, if you are not comfortable with a debugger yet, you may use Log.d() to print debug messages to LogCat. Try printing the ID on each step and see which value is removed and which values exist in the list.

Comment: That sounds good.  I'm thinking it must be the position in the DialogFragment that is causing the error.  I have another Activity that passes "contactListAdapter.getItem(position)" with a putExtra method in an intent to another Activity.  A button click then launches a delete method in that Second Activity that uses that position from the Adapter and getId() and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your click listeners in `onBindViewHolder` method not in `onCreateViewHolder`. If you do this you can get position and item which clicked easily.